# Can Silverlight 4 run SSIS packages, SSRS reports... etc?

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0

Can Silverlight 4 run SSIS packages & SSRS reports directly? What about interacting with Office object models? I am wondering if Silverlight 4 can be used to create full blown Line of Business Apps and for me to skip learning WPF and using RIA services. I know SL is a subset of WCF. I don't know either and want to save time and concentrate on learning SL4 if it does LOB apps?

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, SSIS and SSRS expose a COM interface (though I could be wrong on that).  If they do, then, yes, it would be possible to call SSIS packages through the out-of-browser option in Silverlight 4.  See, for starters, [this video](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-beta-videos/com-object-access-trusted-applications/).

However, this isn't really what Silverlight was designed for.  If your LOB app is just a standard data access/updating thing, then, yeah, Silverlight is a reasonable candidate.  But if you're having to interact with your enterprise infrastructure in any significant way that can't easily be wrapped in a WCF web service, I'd probably stick with WinForms or WPF.  I suspect you'll probably find yourself chasing fewer dead ends.